# libsoup SoupMessage->response_body ->data type issue

Tags: c++, http

I am trying to read the response to an HTTP GET request, which I have confirmed is going through.  I am getting an error when compiling stating that

> SoupMessage->response_body->data is a char not a const char*

It is defined as a `const char*` by the library as shown [in the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/SoupMessageBody.html#SoupMessageBody-struct).

I am using Eclipse and the autocomplete says it's a `const char *` too, but when I build it it still produces errors.

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some insight into why this might be happening and how I could fix it.  As an FYI I am on Ubuntu and Linux GCC Toolchain if that's relevant.

```
const char * getTuned(SoupURI *host){
    std::string request;
    SoupMessage *msg;
    std::cout << soup_uri_get_host(host) << std::endl;
    request = "http://" + std::string(soup_uri_get_host(host)) + ":8080";
    std::cout << request << std::endl;
    session = soup_session_new();
    msg = soup_message_new("GET", request.c_str());
    guint status;
    status = soup_session_send_message(session, msg);
    return *msg->response_body->data;
}
```